# Font are wrong or inconsistent in Kendo PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, kendo-ui

I am having a problem with KendoUI PDF export.  I believe the core "Regular" font loads, but the varients don't seem to be there. am I configuring "bold\semibold\etc" wrong??  The docs are REALLY bad explaining this.

As an example "Work Sans" with font-weight: 700; doesn't show up in the pdf, looks just like regular.  Clearly it's Work Sans, but nothing is bold.

Simple VSCode Project Sample:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w25q38w1makog3w/FontProject.zip?dl=0

So here are my font families from the sass

```
$font-Halant: 'Halant', serif;
$font-IBMPlexSerif: 'IBM Plex Serif', serif;
$font-Lato: 'Lato', sans-serif;
$font-Roboto: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
$font-SourceSansPro: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
$font-WorkSans: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
```

They are all google fonts for the page and the ttfs are saved locally for the kendo export.  Everything looks great on the page, all the fonts are there.

This is how I am defining the fonts for export

```
kendo.pdf.defineFont({
            //Halant
            "Halant": "fonts/Halant/Halant-Regular.ttf",
            "Halant|SemiBold": "fonts/Halant/Halant-SemiBold.ttf",
            "Halant|Bold": "fonts/Halant/Halant-Bold.ttf",
            "Halant|Medium": "fonts/Halant/Halant-Medium.ttf",

        //Roboto
        "Roboto": "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf",
        "Roboto|Bold": "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf",
        "Roboto|Medium": "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf",

        //IBM
        "IBM Plex Serif": "fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif/IBMPlexSerif-Regular.ttf",
        "IBM Plex Serif|Bold": "fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif/IBMPlexSerif-Bold.ttf",
        "IBM Plex Serif|Medium": "fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif/IBMPlexSerif-Medium.ttf",
        "IBM Plex Serif|SemiBold": "fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif/IBMPlexSerif-SemiBold.ttf",

        //Lato
        "Lato": "fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf",
        "Lato|Bold": "fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf",

        //Source Sans Pro
        "Source Sans Pro": "fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf",
        "Source Sans Pro|Bold": "fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf",
        "Source Sans Pro|SemiBold": "fonts/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf",

        //Work Sans
        "Work Sans": "fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Regular.ttf",
        "Work Sans|Bold": "fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf",
        "Work Sans|Medium": "fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Medium.ttf",
        "Work Sans|SemiBold": "fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post was answered by Telerik, gonna post this for others.  Basically just make new font names, specify the files and it should be good.

Now I still *WANT* google fonts for the page so on PDF export I apply a .exporting class to body so I'll just hack these font names in for that.

1) Remove the googlefonts link from the index :

```
<head> 
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Halant:400,600|IBM+Plex+Serif:400,400i,600,600i,700|Lato|Roboto:400,500,700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700|Work+Sans:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet"> --> 
</head>
```

2) Remove the kendo.pdf.defineFont method from resumes.js:

```
kendo.pdf.defineFont({...})
```

3) Use font-face in the resume.css files to load the desired fonts from the local files:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Work Sans";
  src: url("fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Work Sans Bold";
  src: url("fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Notice that the declaration is slightly different for the Bold file. This allows the usage of the font to be changed in the resume.css as follows:

```
.resume.style2 {
  font-family: "Work Sans";
}

.resume.style2 header h3 {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: "Work Sans Bold";
}

.resume.style2 section h4 {
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.1pt;
  font-family: "Work Sans Bold";
}
```

Comment: using this code but not getting font bold in generating pdf